# How do I charge my MOBIB card to take a TEC bus?

Tags: buses, belgium

So I obtained a MOBIB card from the train station and I heard you could also use this card on TEC buses. I'm planning on taking TEC bus A from Charleroi Sud trainstation towards Charleroi Airport. Now how should I charge my MOBIB card, to use it on the bus? Can this be done at regular train stations or do I need to go to special places? I am in Flanders, so not don't have any TEC shop nearby (as far as I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [website of the TEC](http://www.infotec.be/fr-be/acheteruntitre/mobib.aspx):

> Vous disposez d'une carte MOBIB d'un autre opérateur (SNCB, STIB, De
>   Lijn) ?
>
> Vous pouvez charger sur cette carte un titre de transport TEC en vous
>   rendant dans un ESPACE TEC ou à un SELF (automate de vente). Si vous
>   souhaitez acheter un titre via l'E-SHOP ou via EASY PAY, vous devez
>   d'abord vous rendre dans un ESPACE TEC afin de relier votre carte à
>   notre système billettique.

Translation (by me):

> You have a MOBIB card of another operator (SNCB, STIB, De
>   Lijn) ?
>
> You can put your TEC ticket on this card by visiting an ESPACE TEC or at a SELF (vending machine). If you wish to buy a ticket using the E-SHOP or by EASY PAY, you should first visit an ESPACE TEC in order to link your card to our ticket system.

So in your case, you can go to the ESPACE TEC at the station in Charleroi next time you travel to Charleroi Airport. If you ask at that time to do whatever they need to do in order to make the use of the E-SHOP possible, you will be able to buy tickets online from that moment on.